# How in kubernetes retrieve the value of the forwarded port?

Tags: java, service, kubernetes

I am trying to create a service and then communicate with it externally.

```
V1Service service = new V1Service();
V1ServiceSpec spec = new V1ServiceSpec();
spec.addPortsItem(new V1ServicePort().port(25452));
service.setSpec(spec);
...

V1Service kubernetesService = api.createNamespacedService("ns", service, null);
```

When I type `kubectl get services --all-namespaces` command, I see that the port 25452 was forwarded to another automatically allocated port:

```
NAMESPACE TYPE        IP               EXTRENAL IP   PORT(S)
ns        NodePort    10.100.237.201   <none>        25452:32668/TCP
```

How using Java code can I retrieve the value of the new forwarded port (32668)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubernetesService.getSpec().getPorts().get(0).getNodePort()`